# Default block not called if the extension is disabled from advanced

Tags: checkout, ce-1.9.0.1, blocks

I have overridden onepage block in my extension. However When I disable the extension from advanced system configuration My entire checkout page is not being displayed. So please provide me solution to this.

Comment: please disable your extension  from app/etc/module/YourModuleNameSpace_Yourmodule.xml on file <active>false</active>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you disabled module from `System > Configuration > Advanced > Disable` Modules Output will not actually disable that module. It will, as the name suggest, disable modules output.

When you look at

```
abstract class Mage_Core_Block_Abstract
```

In

```
final public function toHtml()
            {
                Mage::dispatchEvent('core_block_abstract_to_html_before', array('block' => $this));
                if (Mage::getStoreConfig('advanced/modules_disable_output/' . $this->getModuleName())) {
                    return '';
                } 

// It is checking If its in disabled mode then just return blank output
    .......
    }
```

thats why it display blank o/p,If you want disabled module the just disabled from `app>etc>modules`